# Apache Tika not working to convert tiff files to text file

Tags: java, filesystems, tiff, apache-tika

I am trying to use Apache Tika for converting tiff files to text format. I have seen the Javadoc, where they have **TiffParser**, so I guess it should convert tiff to text format. 
I tried using it in **windows** and **ubuntu** machine from command-line as well as java code. But it's not extracting the text from tiff.

**In command line:**
java -jar tika-app-1.13.jar -t -i tiffInputFolder -o tiffOutputFolder

**In Java:**

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
 import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
 import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
 import org.apache.tika.parser.image.TiffParser;
 import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

 public class TiffParserImpl {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,SAXException,TikaException {

    String folderPath=args[0];   
    File directory = new File(folderPath);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList){
        System.out.println("Files:"+file);
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

        TiffParser parser = new TiffParser();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        ParseContext pcontext=new ParseContext();

        parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext);
        System.out.println("Contents of the document:" + handler.toString());

    }
}

}
```

I got empty results from both the methods. Has anyone tried converting tiff files?? If yes, how it is done??

Comment: Do you want to OCR the image? Or just get the metadata?

Comment: I want to OCR the image. The tiff files contain some text which I need to extract it to .txt file. I have extracted the metadata using Apache Tika but it didn't extract any text.

Comment: What happens if you [try following the Apache Tika instructions on enabling OCR support](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaOCR)?

Comment: Thank you Gagravarr. There was a dependency using apache tika for image file, tesserract-ocr is used for OCR support for those image files. I installed tesseract in windows machine and I was able to run through command line.